# Multi-Period Time Controls Online

Tags: online-chess, time-control

All online services for playing chess that I am aware of allow the user to specify a time control with a single base time and an increment. I would like to find one that supports a multi-period control, so that more time could be added only after move 40, for example. Does anyone know of a service that does that? The idea is that a friend and I could practice using the controls that will actually be used in real life.

Comment: Those time controls are usually very long time controls for games lasting 4+ hours. Do you really want to play a 4+ hour game online? (I've never seen time being added after move 40 for non-classical games.)

Comment: Also, some websites offer users the option of adding time to your opponent's clock. If it's only for friendly practice games, you could use this manual solution.

Comment: Yes, I really want to play such a game. A classical game online with friends who live far away. Yes, adding time is possible, but not very convenient. It's strange, because it seems like such a simple option for a website to offer.

Comment: On the scale of a 5-6 hour game, I wouldn't mind the <1 minute needed to fix those timers after move 40. And in the end, the best way to practice "real games" is to just play real games (OTB tournaments, classical games), which is different from sitting at your computer for several hours, where you are distracted by lots of other things.

Comment: I agree with you that the best way to practice real games is to play them in person, but as I'm sure you are aware, the opportunity does not always, and in fact frequently does not, exist. All the more so since I want to play with particular friends. I agree with you that pausing to change the clocks (which cannot be done in any precise way anyway) comes at only a minor expense, but the whole point of asking my question was to see whether there were some website where I could have my cake and eat it, too. There is no need to try to persuade me that my question is wrongheaded.